# Android - How to define sets of drawable images to be shown in edittext or text view

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I'm trying to do the next thing - let's say i have a menu with 5 drawable images (could be more but that's not the point), now when a user press on one drawable then it will be shown next a text that is already shown in the edittext.

Also I would like to allow the user add as many drawables as he wants.

So what i do understand is the next code lines -

Using map and defines the pairs of keyword and matching drawable -

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> emoticons = new HashMap<String, Integer>();


emoticons.put("[-smile-]", R.drawable.smile);
emoticons.put("[-tongue-]", R.drawable.tongue);
emoticons.put("[-cool-]", R.drawable.cool);
emoticons.put("[-sad-]", R.drawable.sad);
emoticons.put("[-cry-]", R.drawable.cry);
fillArrayList();

private void fillArrayList() {
    Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> iterator = emoticons.entrySet().iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Entry<String, Integer> entry = iterator.next();
        arrayListSmileys.add(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

First of all - I've decided to define the keywords like the next pattern - [-keyword-] - because I assume in that way it will be much more easy to get the keywords from the String.

Now, the thing that I'm getting stuck in, is how should I read the String, and how to change the keywords from the String into the drawable.

So let's say the user want to write the next line (using the drawables) -

```
I am [-smile-] everything [-cool-]
```

So what I try to do is, something that can read this string and when it getting into         [-keyword-], then it knows to show it to the user as drawable from the map pairs.

Thanks for any kind of help

Answer (score 0):

If I'm working out your problem correctly you want to use "smileys" in your text?

You can use HTML in TextViews and display the images with image tags.

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("I am <img src='img_smile'>smile</img> everything <img src='img_cool'>cool</img>"));
```

Comment: Ok, so how it will know what the src for the image then?